# how can I stop Outlook calendar from syncing?

Tags: calendar

since I updated the OS on my intercept, my outlook calendar is now syncing and I want it to stop.  I only want to see my personal google calendar appts on my phone.  Any ideas how I can turn it off?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Settings -> Accounts and sync`, select your corporate (Exchange) account, and uncheck **Sync calendar**.